# how to merge an array and an object that are related?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I need to merge an array and one object that has a same product id, consider these two as an example:

```js
myArr = [
  {
    "id": 60,
    "productID": 7,
    "reservationDate": "2021-07-29T00:11:30.88",
    "reservationFinishDateAndHour": "2021-07-28T13:00:30.88",
    "reservationStartDateAndHour": "2021-07-28T09:00:30.88",
    "userID": 70,
  },
  {
    "id": 61,
    "productID": 10,
    "reservationDate": "2021-07-29T00:11:30.88",
    "reservationFinishDateAndHour": "2021-07-28T13:00:30.88",
    "reservationStartDateAndHour": "2021-07-28T09:00:30.88",
    "userID": 70,
  }
]
```

```
myObj = {
  "companyID": 1008,
  "createdBy": "Unknown",
  "createdDate": "2021-07-27T00:00:00",
  "finishWorkingHour": "2021-07-27T18:00:00",
  "groupOfImage": null,
  "id": 7,
  "lastModifiedBy": "Ghods",
  "lastModifiedDate": "2021-07-27T00:00:00",
  "productCategories": null,
  "productDetail": "Casual",
  "productName": "Casual",
  "productPrice": 0,
  "startWorkingHour": "2021-07-27T08:00:00",
}
```

and I need by comparing `productID` from `myArr` to `id` in `myObj` get this array:

```js
myResult = [
  {
    "id": 60,
    "productID": 7,
    "reservationDate": "2021-07-29T00:11:30.88",
    "reservationFinishDateAndHour": "2021-07-28T13:00:30.88",
    "reservationStartDateAndHour": "2021-07-28T09:00:30.88",
    "userID": 70,
  },
{
  "companyID": 1008,
  "createdBy": "Unknown",
  "createdDate": "2021-07-27T00:00:00",
  "finishWorkingHour": "2021-07-27T18:00:00",
  "groupOfImage": null,
  "id": 7,
  "lastModifiedBy": "Ghods",
  "lastModifiedDate": "2021-07-27T00:00:00",
  "productCategories": null,
  "productDetail": "Casual",
  "productName": "Casual",
  "productPrice": 0,
  "startWorkingHour": "2021-07-27T08:00:00",
}
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get rid of the items with a different `productID` and push `myObj` to the resulting array:

```js
var myArr = [
  {
    "id": 60,
    "productID": 7,
    "reservationDate": "2021-07-29T00:11:30.88",
    "reservationFinishDateAndHour": "2021-07-28T13:00:30.88",
    "reservationStartDateAndHour": "2021-07-28T09:00:30.88",
    "userID": 70,
  },
  {
    "id": 61,
    "productID": 10,
    "reservationDate": "2021-07-29T00:11:30.88",
    "reservationFinishDateAndHour": "2021-07-28T13:00:30.88",
    "reservationStartDateAndHour": "2021-07-28T09:00:30.88",
    "userID": 70,
  }
]
var myObj = {
  "companyID": 1008,
  "createdBy": "Unknown",
  "createdDate": "2021-07-27T00:00:00",
  "finishWorkingHour": "2021-07-27T18:00:00",
  "groupOfImage": null,
  "id": 7,
  "lastModifiedBy": "Ghods",
  "lastModifiedDate": "2021-07-27T00:00:00",
  "productCategories": null,
  "productDetail": "Casual",
  "productName": "Casual",
  "productPrice": 0,
  "startWorkingHour": "2021-07-27T08:00:00",
}

const result = myArr.filter((e, i) => e.productID == myObj.id);
result.push(myObj)
console.log(result);
```